# duplicate props file when training new StanfordCoreNLP tagger in scala

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to train a new StanfordCoreNLP tagger using the following line of code:

`MaxentTagger.main(Seq("-props", "src/resources/tagger/mycustom.tagger.props").toArray)`.

The data files inside `src/resources/tagger/mydata.txt`. But a second copy of the props file keeps magically appearing at the the same level as `src`. By second copy, I mean exacty the same, with the same custom file name and the same custom values inside the file. I tried deleting this file several times, but it keeps reappearing.

Alternatively, I tried deleting the one inside my `src/resources/tagger/` file and using only the one at the same level as `src`. But the opposite thing happened. When I tried to save the trained model inside the resources folder, a second copy of the props file appeared along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal.  The tagger stores a copy of the properties used for the model along with the model as a record and to assist with recreating the training process if one needed to.